# Split testing transactional emails

Tags: email, testing, content-management-system

I'm trying to figure out a solution to manage our transaction emails (such as the welcome email, you've got a bid, etc...)

We would like to be able to allow marketing to manage the content of the emails, and create split tests to test content / subject lines / etc...

Ideally we could invent our own success metrics to report back to the email management system (such as user completed registration, accepted bid, etc...).

Right now we have our emails in templates using stringtemplate.  The code replaces tokens with the correct content for that email.

Strongmail is a potential solution, but it is pricey - anybody have experience with alternatives?

Comment: How many messages/day on average?

Comment: 30K or so.  Although we could do fewer for testing is its a per send cost.  I'd prefer something that isnt though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com)?

Currently, it's a layer between your web app and your SMTP server which has additional features for your transactional emails.

With PostageApp, you are able to create two different templates and have them triggered alternately with different content and subject lines. However, the metrics that you would want to use for A/B testing aren't built into the system yet, so I'm not sure if it would be a good fit for you.

**Full Disclosure:** I work for The Working Group, the company that created PostageApp.

But if you do have questions about what we can help you with and what we can't, definitely let me know and I can answer plenty of questions for you!

Comment: Awarding points - this is at least the closest to what i'm looking for.

Comment: Nick, if you like, you can send me an email at jon@postageapp.com so we can start a conversation, and maybe if you're looking for something on our roadmap, we can prioritize it? Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: I've been looking for something like Postage App since Apr 2010. While it doesn't have the SQL integration I'm looking for; I'm more than happy to write some api code and use your guys for templating and delivery!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705910/looking-for-an-email-report-templating-engine-with-database-backend-for-end-us

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for the same kind of service, and https://www.sendwithus.com/ seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.cakemail.com/

It is a third party, you design your workflows and give them your contacts.

I work for a 6 million a year website company and we direct all our clients to them, so far so good, everyone is happy.

You have to contact them to have a price but you can get a free account for testing